# What is the difference between ttyUSB and ttyACM?

Tags: tty, serial-port

I have a homemade device for measuring night sky brightness (astronomy). I am now writing the program in c for data acquisition. I noticed that on my laptop, the device (when connected) gets `ttyACM0`. However, on the lab desktop (approx. 6 years old), the device is connected as `ttyUSB0`. So, I am interested in knowing what is the difference between `ttyACM` and `ttyUSB`?

Comment: https://www.rfc1149.net/blog/2013/03/05/what-is-the-difference-between-devttyusbx-and-devttyacmx/

Comment: That's a great reference, could any post an answer.